# Share folders through a tethering connection

Tags: nautilus, samba, android, shared-folders, tethering

I have following network structure

```
PC  <-- USB cable -->   Android Smartphone <--> MyWiFi
IP=192.168.42.41        IP=192.168.35.115       IP=192.168.35.254
NM=255.255.255.0        NM=???                  NM=255.255.255.0
DG=192.168.42.129       DG=???                  DG=???

Laptop <--------------> MyWiFi
IP=192.168.35.112       IP=192.168.35.254
NM=255.255.255.0        NM=255.255.255.0
DG=192.168.35.254       DG=???
```

... where `MyWiF`i is my home WiFi network

**Note:** The PC can "ping" the Laptop, but the Laptop cannot "ping" the PC.

When I `traceroute 192.168.35.254` from the PC, I get the following:

```
traceroute 192.168.35.254
traceroute to 192.168.35.254 (192.168.35.254), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.42.129 (192.168.42.129)  2.163 ms  2.870 ms  3.339 ms
 2  192.168.35.254 (192.168.35.254)  14.562 ms  14.915 ms  11.876 ms
```

Routing from the laptop is:

```
ip route
default via 192.168.35.254 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.35.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.35.112  metric 600
```

So it seems confirmed that my Android Phone stands as gateway between the PC and the WIFI router.

Both computers PC and Laptop have Ubuntu installed and Nautilus + Samba in order to share folders. The problem is that the PC cannot see the share folders of the Laptop

I have already shared folders between other computers that connect directly to MyWiFi, but I think in this case the tethering is spoiling the sharing.

*How can I share folders, even though I am connecting the PC to the WiFi via tethering?*

Comment: How is the PC tethered to the Android? Cable? Bluetooth? can the PC ping the default gateway of `MyWiFi`? Can it ping 1.1.1.1?  Please [edit] your question to provide this valuable info and then leave a comment @Fabby  **0:-)**

Comment: This is confusing,... are you sure you use tethering ?

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for the questions. I just did what you asked for. Every `ping` worked properly.

Comment: Ah. Please [edit] your question and provide the whole picture in the `PC <-- USB cable --> Android Smartphone <--> MyWiFi` line: all of their IP addresses and Default gateways because you don't have a samba issue but a networking issue.  also add the full samba config to https://paste.ubuntu.com and provide a link to that in your question too. so make your question easy to understand from a full networking perspective...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Hey guys, I do not think I can provide more useful infos. The full samba config, how can I get it? ´:-) (I think I deserve part of the bounty ;))

Comment: @user68186 can I mount folders with `sftp` or `sshfs`? But may be I loose the power of being in a local network. If I use an application that goes through the internet, then the data transmission is much slower. ;) I want to connect in Local Network

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus samba config is located in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Please see my [revision](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1158257/revisions) to your question and *please fill in the blanks* I.E. `???` as you're having a network problem, not a samba problem.

Comment: I agree with @Fabby this is a network issue, specifically having two subnets. The simple solution would be to connect the PC to the router by an Ethernet cable or a WiFi dongle. Then you will have both PC and laptop on the same subnet.

Comment: @Fabby Here is the samba configuration https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3Q67DJ6Spc/   Please, tell me which command do I have to use to get the addresses of my smartphone. By the way, thanks a lot (!) the edits on my question look neat.

Comment: I don't know what you have installed on your Android so that is more of an [android.se] question.  If you have filled in all the ??? I can give you a solution that will work for the entire network.  If you do, please ping me again... **:-)**

Comment: @Fabby, yes please present a solution. It can be a blessing for anyone looking for an answer, or even trying to learn a bit more of networking in linux

Comment: You have to [edit] your question and fill in the `???` first. @loved.by.Jesus  I need all the information to make it work as you wish.  With the information I currently have, the only thing I can answer now is: *Put samba on the PC instead of the laptop...* (which is probably not what you want.)

Answer (score 2):

Here your Android Smartphone indeed works as gateway but partially you also have to configure routes from laptop side.

The reason behind PC cannot see the share folders of the Laptop is that Laptop routes packets through your wifi router.  You need configure your android smartphone's ip address as gateway in your laptop.

Currently gateway of laptop is router. Please remove 192.168.35.254 ip address and configure smartphone as gateway 192.168.35.115 in your laptop's network configuration. After applying configuration, it should work.

You can check routes of laptop using `route -n` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ketan Patel, it really worked! Just by replacing the gateway I could access the PC from the laptop and, not only `ping` the PC's address, but also mount samba from the laptop by standard command `smb://192.168.42.41/folder_name` on nautilus

Answer (score 0):

Because the PC can "ping" the Laptop, I can at least access the Samba shared folders of the Laptop (IP `192.168.35.112`) from the PC. I have to use following command in the nautilus bar of the PC.

```
smb://192.168.35.112/name-of-shared-folder
```

In that way I can do at least exchange from the PC.

### Caveat

The same as the other answers. The IP of the Laptop may change, and therefore the command should be adapted.